# error TS7053 when try to get an object with a key

Tags: angular

When I try to extract an object from the response I get an error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

```
\\ product.service.ts:

  getProducts() {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .pipe(
        map(this.listProduct)
      );
  }

  listProduct (prod: object) {

      let products : Product[] = [];

      if ( prod !== null ) {

        Object.keys(prod).forEach( key => {

          let product: Product = prod[key]; // an error appears here
          
          product.id = key;

          products.push(product);

        })
      }
      return products;
  }
```

maybe the reason is "id?" but that was the only solution that worked

```
\\ product.modelo.ts:

export class Product {
    id?: string;       
    name!: string;
    quantity!: number;
    description!: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set prod paramert to `{ [key: string]: Product; }` type. You can alson create new type and referece it.

```
type ProdObjects = {
  [key: string]: Product;
};

function listProduct (prod: ProdObjects) {
...
```

All other hacks are bad practice

Answer (score -1):

It is complaining about the type of prod because it doesn't know it.
Try this

```
let product: Product = (<any>prod).key;
```